# How to bounds in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

So ive got a 2000x2000 image as a CRS map where i need to fit -600000 +600000 coordinates, but the image becomes so zoomed that im obviously not doing it right, i guess the program does not know how to combine and calculate that by itself to fit the units into pixels, or does it have a setting for that?

I guess it still makes each pixel of the image approx 600units big but i guess thats accurate enough for what im trying to do.

Coordinates themselves seem to be working as the center of the image is exactly spot on.

```js
    var mapOptions = {
            center: [11999, 9199],
            minZoom: 0,
            maxZoom: 0
         }
        
         
         // Creating a map object
        var map = L.map('bigmapleaf', {
            crs: L.CRS.Simple
        }, mapOptions);
        var bounds = [[600000,-600000], [-600000,600000]];
        var image = L.imageOverlay('../pictures/map.png', bounds).addTo(map);
         // Adding layer to the map
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setView( center, 1);
```

Edit:

Now i have managed to find the math that makes the map the right size without any zooming with good precision, but i need to make the map to respond to those kind of large units which i believe requires another conversion back to the original units which does not feel right. I wish i could work with the large units and let leaflet do all the map view conversions. Maybe i try to make a script that discusses both ways with their own units.

Still waiting if someone knows easy answer for my troubles.

In addition to being easier working with them large units, i could also make the map with absolute accuracy.

Comment: Read https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html (again), specially the part which says «we can set `minZoom` to values lower than zero».

Comment: Yes i tried multiple ways to set the minZoom with not a slight change.Now i thought i must of attempted too small numbers for the changes to be seen so calculated the exact minZoom needed for the bounds and that would be -4755, to no avail, the image wont change in any direction.Maybe it is just too large of a number?

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/W3k7JdhibZIoiJoq). Remember that the `L.map` factory methods only takes **two** arguments but you're passing **three**, therefore ignoring stuff.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was just that. No wonder it didnt feel to work at all. But no errors were found so i was not seeing it. Im not really a js guy